# Google Analytics issue on Xamarin.ios

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am building xamarin.forms project and integrated google analytics for ios and droid.
Currently I used Google Analytics for iOS framework by installed nuget for xamarin.ios. By the way, when I build ios, native library linking failed exception happens.
How can I fix this issue?
Here is exception lists.

> Error     Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_lref_log_delete. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_lref_log_delete. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_max_gref_get. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Java.Interop.Runtime._monodroid_max_gref_get. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_weak_gref_new. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_weak_gref_new. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_gref_get. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.AndroidObjectReferenceManager._monodroid_gref_get. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_getifaddrs. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment._monodroid_getifaddrs. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_gref_log_new. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_gref_log_new. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _monodroid_typemap_managed_to_java. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_typemap_managed_to_java. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_freeifaddrs. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment._monodroid_freeifaddrs. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_lref_log_delete. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_lref_log_delete. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_detect_cpu_and_architecture. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment._monodroid_detect_cpu_and_architecture. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_gref_log_delete. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_gref_log_delete. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Java.Interop.TypeManager.monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_timezone_get_default_id. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment._monodroid_timezone_get_default_id. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_lref_log_new. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_lref_log_new. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_weak_gref_delete. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_weak_gref_delete. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_get_identity_hash_code. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_get_identity_hash_code. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
>   Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: __monodroid_gref_log. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Android.Runtime.JNIEnv._monodroid_gref_log. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same weird error. My fix was to remove the **Mono.Android** reference from **PCL** and then clean and rebuild fixed all the above errors.

In my case **Mono.Android** reference was actually a required reference but, to get rid of these errors, I commented out the code in **PCL** that was using **Mono.Android** . After a successful build ( without Mono.Android ), I reverted the code in **PCL** and added **Mono.Android** reference back to PCL . Surprisingly a clean and rebuild with **Mono.Android** as a reference in PCL worked this time ! I have no clue how .